# Nodemailer Gmail timeout

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, nodemailer

I am having trouble with sending emails to my Gmail account.
I am getting a timeout error. And it puzzles me, because I basically copied the settings from a working project I did before.
But then I tried the working project, and it gives me the same error.
As far as I know Nodemailer's default port for Gmail is 465 which uses SSL, so this is turned on.
I have tried three different Gmail accounts, two have 2FA, one of them has setup XOAuth, the third I turned on less secure apps. Everything failed with the same error.

Here is the code snippet, where I think the trouble is:

```
smtpConfig =
  service: "Gmail"
  connectionTimeout : "7000" #waiting for 60s is annoying
  greetingTimeout : "7000"
#  auth:
#    XOAuth2:
#      user: receiverEmail
##      pass: appSpecificPassword
#      clientId: myClientId
#      clientSecret: itIsMySecret
#      refreshToken: myRefreshToken
  auth:
    user: receiverEmail
    pass: appSpecificPassword
  secure: true # use SSL
  debug: true
```

I later put it into a function. In between I had to put the envelope together.

```
smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport(smtpConfig), ->
   #Setup configs are on top, because we need to config before we use the POST method according to express
)
```

This one doesn't even fire, when you put a console.log in there.

On Nodemailers Github I found the following to try out in the terminal:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
```

which should give a nice 200 response, but it doesn't, it gives me a timeout. Every other available port responded with the same.
I asked a friend to try it out on his computer and it works fine for him. So I am back searching for the problem on my computer - maybe on my operating system, node version, do we setup the configs differently and I didn't notice?
I am running out of options, so I am seeking for help here.

My firewall is off, no fuzzes about setting up extra ports in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive checking with my system and my internet provider I found that my router didn't like my internal IP address. So I renewed my DHCL leasing.

If you ever encounter the same problem, here are some tips for debugging.

1. **Check for viruses:** Along my deep research on the internet, I found the tip that viruses can block ports. So if you don't have a scanner, download one.
2. **Check your firewall:** Most common trouble. I checked my firewall and noticed it was offline.
3. **Use network utilities:** Do a port scan and try to ping the IP addresses
4. Check your email address with your **local email client**, try to send an email. Check incoming server and outgoing server configurations.
5. **Check your network:** Ask your provider if it is blocking email providers. Renew your network configurations.
6. **Check your Google account** if it is blocking your IP address. Happens often, if you send out a bunch of emails marked as spam, or if your account was hacked and used by somebody to send out spam.